# failed to load or find registered .net data provider MySql connector/NET

Tags: mysql, ssis

I have installed Connector/.NET 8.1.0 on my machine. Installation succeeded.
When I open VS 2019 SSIS project and trying to create connect manager(ADO.NET source)

I am getting error after selecting New connection.NET provider\MySql Data Provider

> Error: Failed to find or load the registered .NET Framework data provider

I have checked GAC, I can see MySql.Data.dll in it

What is the issue? Why am I getting that error even after successful installation?

I have tried even SSMS\Import data wizard. I am getting the same error when selected .NET framework data provider for MySQL.

After a long search on google, I found that we need to amend <system.Data) section in machine.config

I have checked GAC, I can see MySql.Data.dll in it

I have tried even SSMS\Import data wizard. I am getting the same error when selected .NET framework data provider for MySQL.

After a long search on google, I found that we need to amend 'system.Data' section in machine.config

My machine.config currently showing as below

```
runtime/>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: As VS 2019 is a 32bit application, did you install the 32bit driver, 64bit connector, or both?